# Save mail message as a file on Linux using sendmail

Tags: linux, email, logging, sendmail

I have an application running on several RHEL 5.8 systems which monitors and alerts (via email).  I need to create a durable log of these alerts locally on each node.

I think the easiest way to do this would be to add a local email user to the alerts and then use **mailbox settings or a script** (if needed) to save each message on a local filesystem

I would settle for message body dumped to a text file (one file per email.)

It would be better if it could extract time, host, subject, & body as seperate fields for consumption by an open source log reader.

My systems are using sendmail 8.1 and I would prefer to stick with it, although I also have postfix 2.3.3 available.

Comment: Which program do you use as local mailer? See lines after Mlocal line in `/etc/mail/sendndmail.cf`.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip, not sure if you're asking for values of Mlocal or line AFTER it (Mprog)
  
Mlocal,         P=/usr/bin/procmail, F=lsDFMAw5:/|@qSPfhn9, S=EnvFromL/HdrFromL, R=EnvToL/HdrToL,
                T=DNS/RFC822/X-Unix,
                A=procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u
 
Mprog,          P=/usr/sbin/smrsh, F=lsDFMoqeu9, S=EnvFromL/HdrFromL, R=EnvToL/HdrToL, D=$z:/,
                T=X-Unix/X-Unix/X-Unix,
                A=smrsh -c $u

Answer (score 2):

As you reported your sendmail uses procmail as local mailer => create special OS user account (e.g. log_user) and use `~log_user/.procmailrc` to instruct procmail to deliver messages to [maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) folder.

~log_user/.procmailrc

```
# deliver ALL messages to ~/maillog/ maildir. 
# see "man procmailex" for email sorting examples 
:0
maillog/
```

Comment: I've done just as you described and it does a rough but workable job of it +1.  A quick look at procmailex manual makes me think I can get closer to what I want.  If so, I will post my final .procmailrc and mark up your answer. Thanks!